# Авторизация не проходит Python

Tags: python, парсер

Ребята, только не смейтесь, решил для практики в парсинге попрактиковаться на сайте xvideos)) Открыл панель разработчика в браузере хром , ввёл логин и пароль , получил следующие данные  для метода POST

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее вот мой код

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    file_url =r'C:\Users\483\Desktop\файлы\xvid'
    link_enter='https://www.xvideos.com/account'
    
    data = {
    
        'signin-form[login]': 'secret@mail.ru',
        'signin-form[password]': 'secret))',
        'signin-form[rememberme]': 'on'
    
    }
    
    
    headers ={
        'accept':'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    
    sess = requests.Session()
    req =sess.post(link_enter,headers=headers,data=data)
    print(req.text)
```

На выходе получается html код. Reponse_status тоже пишет что всё в замечательно( код 200). Но когда я пытаюсь сохранить этот html код в блокноте,(копировал из консоли ,которая вывела print() и вставил в notepad++)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и запускаю его, я вижу что страница как была неавторизованная, так и осталась((( Почему так происходит и как это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
====================День второй====================

Решил парсингом вытащить csrf токен из html файла, благо они в виде скрытых полей присутствуют там.[![введите сюда описание изображения][5]][5]

Ничего не вышло, пишет , что страница была открыта давно, хотя программа за милисекунду сработала

Вот обновленный код попытки всё исправить и сама ошибка

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
file_url =r'C:\Users\483\Desktop\файлы\xvid'
link_enter='https://www.xvideos.com/account'
take = requests.get(link_enter)
soup_first=BeautifulSoup(take.text,'lxml')
CSRF = soup_first.find('input',id='signin-form_csrf_token').get('value')



data = {
'signin-form[csrf_token]': f'{CSRF}',

    'signin-form[login]': 'login',
    'signin-form[password]': 'pass',
    'signin-form[rememberme]': 'on'

}


headers ={
    'accept':'image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

sess = requests.Session()
req =sess.post(link_enter,headers=headers,data=data)
print(req.text)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, как вы "пытались сохранить html код в блокноте".

Comment: @СергейКох исправил,  боюсь всё равно не поможет))

Comment: Попробуйте Selenium для этого

Answer (score 1):

CSRF токен надо получить с сайта перед отправкой формы. Обычно найти его можно в куках. Поместите этот токен в POST форму.

Comment: Он еще может в самой form заполняться среди тегов input (они скрытые)